# Unity Vuforia Noisy Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia, noise

I'm develop a simple Video App with Vuforia and Unity and I'm having a weird trouble.

The App starts normally and sudenly the camera starts with a noise; I've tested my app in 3 devices (2 Samsung and 1 Motorola), and the trouble persist in Samsung devices (S6 and S6 Edge) but not in my Motorola device.

Here is my logcat:

```
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_OUTPUT]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:85) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1678]):node(3AA_OUTPUT)->getBuffer() fail, index(5), frameCount(2333), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_PREVIEW]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:91) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_PREVIEW)->getBuffer() fail, index(4), frameCount(2333), ret(-1)
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_CAPTURE]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:89) returned with error (64) 
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_CAPTURE)->getBuffer() fail, index(1), frameCount(2333), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]- ERR(m_getBuffer[1908]):frameCount(2333) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(-1) !=   NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-  WARN(m_getBufferThreadFunc[1326]):m_getBuffer fail, ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1370]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(2333)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_putBuffer[1562]):clean frame, frameCount(2333)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_completeFrame[2286]):NOT DONE frameCount(2333)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-WARN(m_putBufferThreadFunc[1310]):m_putbuffer fail, ret(-38)
W/ExynosCamera( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][]-WARN(m_removeFrameFromList):frame count mismatch: expected(2333), current(2332)
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_OUTPUT]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:85) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1678]):node(3AA_OUTPUT)->getBuffer() fail, index(6), frameCount(2334), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_PREVIEW]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:91) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_PREVIEW)->getBuffer() fail, index(7), frameCount(2334), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_CAPTURE]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:89) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_CAPTURE)->getBuffer() fail, index(0), frameCount(2334), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1908]):frameCount(2334) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(-1) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-WARN(m_getBufferThreadFunc[1326]):m_getBuffer fail, ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1370]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(2334)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_putBuffer[1562]):clean frame, frameCount(2334)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_completeFrame[2286]):NOT DONE frameCount(2334)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-WARN(m_putBufferThreadFunc[1310]):m_putbuffer fail, ret(-38)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_OUTPUT]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:85) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1678]):node(3AA_OUTPUT)->getBuffer() fail, index(7), frameCount(2335), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_PREVIEW]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:91) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_PREVIEW)->getBuffer() fail, index(6), frameCount(2335), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraNode( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][3AA_CAPTURE]-ERR(m_dqBuf):exynos_v4l2_dqbuf(fd:89) returned with error (64)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1793]):node(3AA_CAPTURE)->getBuffer() fail, index(2), frameCount(2335), ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1908]):frameCount(2335) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(-1) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-WARN(m_getBufferThreadFunc[1326]):m_getBuffer fail, ret(-1)
E/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1370]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(2335)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_putBuffer[1562]):clean frame, frameCount(2335)
D/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-DEBUG(m_completeFrame[2286]):NOT DONE frameCount(2335)
W/ExynosCameraMCPipe( 2974): [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-WARN(m_putBufferThreadFunc[1310]):m_putbuffer fail, ret(-38)
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
I/EDMNativeHelperService( 3564): isCameraEnabled
D/ShotSingle( 2974): CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X
```

And a link to a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-Pf_gUQXoI&feature=youtu.be)

Once again, is a simple Video App with a button to take screenshot and thats all.

Hope some one knows how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you mean "noise"?

Comment: @JoeBlow You can saw it in the Video I put in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem , Please Follow these steps:

1. Switch Platform To Android .
2. Go To : Player Settings > Player > Other Settings
3. Uncheck (Auto Api Check) option.
4. Remove Vulkan Item (by minus icon.)
5. Add OpenGLES3  & OpenGLES2 .